# Visual studio 2015 deploy to windows 10 phone

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to deploy a test application to my Lumia 950XL however running into an issue where Visual studio automatically tries to deploy it to an SD card??? I don't have one and not intending to use one either so it's kind of weird that it just assumes that every phone will always have SD card? I haven't found a way to change it so far :(

Here is the error

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: App5, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Deploying to SD Card...
1>Creating a new clean layout...
1>Copying files: Total 16 mb to layout...
1>Error : DEP2100 : Cannot copy the file "C:\Users\Arturs\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App5\App5\bin\ARM\Debug\App5.exe" to the target machine "127.0.0.1". 
1>Exception from HRESULT: 0x92330043
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: it's seems strange to deploy to localhost

Comment: I'm deploying to a device. Not quite sure why visual studio tries to deploy to a localhost :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to deploy to a remote machine instead of a device.
I've figured this out now :)